# Beamer template used by Bhargava

Tags: beamer

Does anybody have a template for the beamer presentation used by Bhargava
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LwD0HFhLIw)   ?

I would also be happy with anything similar to the one he used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This isn't how this site works I am afraid, we cannot give templates or advice based on a paused screen of a YouTube video URL (that doesn't work too), if you edit into your question an image and how your current document looks then maybe this will be on topic but as it stands I do not think it is

Comment: I have edited the link and hopefully now the entire YouTube video should be viewable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very much like the default beamer theme with a custom background colour, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{myback}{RGB}{250,238,195}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=myback}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

---

If you like this style, maybe have a look at https://github.com/jrnold/beamercolorthemesolarized

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one small thing:  how do I get the font he uses? (it seems different from your template above)

Comment: @Dekimshita Please update your question to include a screenshot